# access fields in json object with unique identifiers

Tags: json, jq

I'm having trouble understanding jq.  I'm even having trouble articulating what I want to learn.

I think I want a wildcard?  my desire is, given a json snippet like this:

```
{
  "logs": {
    "-MnpQaRONGXz9tff-W": {
      "points": 10,
      "type": "signup"
    },
    "-N5qlX1mQ3SYA9RXdE": {
      "points": 15,
      "type": "welcome"
    },
    "-N5rx8PAcNgWu25zRf": {
      "points": 5,
      "type": "vote"
    },
    "-N5s29TyZ33snUqC5X": {
      "points": 5,
      "type": "vote"
    }
  },
  "total": 35
}
```

Count how many times a certain type appears, or even just output all the types into a file.

This totally doesn't work (and in the simplified example doesn't make sense):

```
cat test.json | jq '.logs | * | .type'
```

would get me a simple object or listing of the types .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a stream of all the "type" values of all objects, no matter how deeply nested:

```
 .. | select(.type?) | .type
```

In your particular case, the following would suffice:

```
.[] | select(type == "object") | .[].type
```

To produce a tabulation:

```
def tabulate: reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i] += 1 );

[.[] | select(type == "object") | .[].type] | tabulate
```

Given your input, the output would be:

`{
  "signup": 1,
  "welcome": 1,
  "vote": 2
}`

Comment: This lead me to exactly what I needed! These hints helped me gain insight I was missing while trying to parse the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Not a `jq`-only answer, but you can get a list of all the `type` fields, then pipe that through `uniq -c` to get a count.

```
$ jq '.logs[] | .type' tmp.json | uniq -c
    1 signup
    1 welcome
    2 vote
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses **tostream** and **reduce**

```
reduce (tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v] (
  {}
; if $p[-1] == "type" then .[$v] += 1 else . end  
)
```

output with sample data

```
{
  "signup": 1,
  "welcome": 1,
  "vote": 2
}
```